# Can :key be used without v-for in VUE?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, transition

I use VUE  to animate the slider (a list of images). There are two/three slides, each consisting of maximum 9 images. I have a computed property `slide` which returns the current set of images. There is another property `start` which stands for the number of the first image of a current slide. The `<ul>` element is the direct descendant of `<transition>`, so the animation takes place only when `<ul>`'s key changes. The first snippet is how I'd like to solve the problem. It is working but I can't find any information if it's ok to use a :key property on an element without v-for loop.

How was the problem solved untill now? There were two v-for loops. Slide computed property returned [slide] and artificially looped through one-element table. The problem I see is that v-for loops take the whole objects as :key and it's not what documentation recommends. The second snippet is how the code looks right now.

```
        <transition>
            <ul :key="this.start">
                <li v-for="image in slide" :key="image.id">
                    <a>
                        <img />
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </transition>
        <!--CURRENTLY-->
        <transition>
            <ul v-for="slide in slides" :key="slide">
                <li v-for="image in slide" :key="image">
                    <a>
                        <img />
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </transition>
```

Comment: Seems to be yes https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#key

Comment: Would be better to understand your problem if you frame it as, What you are trying to achieve and what are the problems you are facing.

Comment: @VaibhavSingh Singh it is a slider component which takes ~18 images, divides it into portions (depending on the number of slots available to display on one slide) and displays in the form of animated slides. For example 9 images (1st slide) => animation => 9 images (2nd slide) => animation => 9 images (1st slide) and so on. CbaConnier's post seems to answer the question. I don't have any idea why I haven't noticed it in the docs. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked me to post my comment as answer, I will simply quote the documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key

> It can also be used to force replacement of an element/component
> instead of reusing it. This can be useful when you want to:
>
> - Properly trigger lifecycle hooks of a component
> - Trigger transitions
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> <transition>
>   <span :key="text">{{ text }}</span>
> </transition>
> ```
>
> When `text` changes, the `<span>` will always be replaced instead of
> patched, so a transition will be triggered.